# Inheritance of Form attributes (Label, GroupBox etc.) in powershell

Tags: powershell

Im looking for inheritance in powershell. I have a lot of labels, groupBoxes, dropDowns etc. in my Windows form, they are for example like this:

```
$amuletLabelValueDmg = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$amuletLabelValueDmg.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$amuletLabelValueDmg.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20) 
$amuletLabelValueDmg.Text = 'Value'
$groupBoxAmulet.Controls.Add($amuletLabelValueDmg)

$amuletLabelHealth = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$amuletLabelHealth.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$amuletLabelHealth.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20) 
$amuletLabelHealth.Text = 'Health'
$groupBoxAmulet.Controls.Add($amuletLabelHealth)

$amuletLabelResistance = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$amuletLabelResistance.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60) 
$amuletLabelResistance.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20) 
$amuletLabelResistance.Text = 'Resistance'
$groupBoxAmulet.Controls.Add($amuletLabelResistance)
```

I´m looking for inheritance of Label in this case (or you can picture yourself groupBox or dropDown instead of label, princip is same). I dont wanna copy, paste hundreads of Labels i would like to use inheritance and just call some Class with parameters.

I tried to use function but very soon i realized i will always have just one instance, so this will not work. My friend advise me to use something like Class in powershell and instead of those rows above just call this class with new instance. But i´m little bit lost. Do anyone know how to "replicate" a lot of labels? I imagine solution like this:

```
class labelValueDmg {
    variables and definition of label 
}

$amuletLabelValueDmg = New-Object labelValueDmg
$beltLabelValueDmg = New-Object labelValueDmg
```

Is there something like that in powershell or how would you solve this problem ? If u have 50 labels, 50 groupBoxes etc...

[1] Actualy I found another way to solve this. As far as I know you can use in my case a simple function to do this. And its more effective. I declare function like this >>

```
function createNewObject {
    param (
        [int[]] $Location,
        [int[]] $Size,
        [string] $Type,
        [string] $Text
    )

   if ($Type -eq 'Label') { $newObject = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label }
   elseif ($Type -eq 'TextBox') { $newObject = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox }
   elseif ($Type -eq 'CheckBox') { $newObject = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox }
   elseif ($Type -eq 'Button') { $newObject = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button }
   elseif ($Type -eq 'GroupBox') { $newObject = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox }
   elseif ($Type -eq 'RadioButton') { $newObject = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton }

   $newObject.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size $Location[0], $Location[1]
   $newObject.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size $Size[0], $Size[1]
   $newObject.Text = $Text

   return $newObject
}
```

Then i Will call this function with new variable for example >>

```
$amuletLabelValueDmg = createNewObject(20,10) (40,10) 'Label' 'Value'
$cloakTextBox = createNewObject(40,10) (40,10) 'TextBox' 'Cloak'
```

I decided this is very good way to call just one function with variable $Type where I decide if object is label, textBox or whatever.
After all I show object in form thanks to your code.

```
$objForm.Controls.AddRange(@(
    $amuletLabelValueDmg
    $cloakTextBox
))
```

As far as I know this is very handy way to deal with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can significantly **cut down the "noise"  and repetitiveness in your code** with the following techniques, which do not require inheritance / type extensions<sup>[1]</sup>:

---

**Use `New-Object` with the `-Property` parameter**, to which you can pass a *hashtable* of properties, which avoids having to create a variable first and then having to assign properties individually:

```
$amuletLabelValueDmg = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label -Property @{
  Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 10, 20
  Size = New-Object Drawing.Size 60, 20
  Text = 'Value'
}
$groupBoxAmulet.Controls.Add($amuletLabelValueDmg)
```

Note:

- I've further shortened the code by omitting the `System.` prefix from the type names, which is generally *optional* in PowerShell (except in `Add-Type`, `Update-TypeData`, and `Update-FormatData` calls and `using assembly` and `using namespace` statements).
- As an aside: Note how I've changed the syntax of some `New-Object` calls, e.g.,  Drawing.Size(60,20)`to`New-Object Drawing.Size 60,20`. The no-whitespace`(60,20)`syntax should be avoided, because it is based on mistaking the syntax for a _method call_, which it isn't:`60, 20`is an array _argument_ that is bound to the (implied)`-ArgumentList` parameter; arguments are passed without parentheses, separated by whitespace.

---

In **PSv5+** you can shorten this with **casts** and the **static `::new()` method** on type literals in lieu of `New-Object`, as well as with the **`using namespace` statement for shortening type names**:

```
# Load the System.Windows.Forms assembly
# which implicitly loads System.Drawing too.
using assembly System.Windows.Forms

# Declare implied namespaces, so that types from
# the loaded assemblies can be referred to by mere name
# (e.g., 'Form' instead of 'System.Windows.Forms')
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing

$amuletLabelValueDmg = [Label] @{
  Location = [Point]::new(10, 20)
  Size = [Size]::new(60, 20)
  Text = 'Value'
}
$groupBoxAmulet.Controls.Add($amuletLabelValueDmg)
```

---

In either case you can create **simple function wrappers** (using PSv5+ here for brevity; the function could and should be made much more robust):

```
function New-Label {
  param(
    [int[]] $Location,
    [int[]] $Size,
    [string] $Text
  )
  # Create and output a new label control
  [Label] @{
    Location = [Point]::new($Location[0], $Location[1])
    Size = [Size]::new($Size[0], $Size[1])
    Text = $Text
  }
}

$amuletLabelValueDmg = New-Label 10,20 60,20 Value
```

---

Finally, you can reduce the need for auxiliary variables by passing an array literal to the container control's `Controls.AddRange()` method (assumes the presence of the `New-Label` function defined above):

```
  $groupBoxAmulet.Controls.AddRange(@(
     New-Label 10,20 60,20 Value
     New-Label 10,40 60,20 Health
     New-Label 10,60 60,20 Resistance
  ))
```

---

[1] While I personally think it's not worth it, if you did want to do it **with inheritance / type extensions**, you'd have to **attach your custom control-creation code to the control *type object*** (e.g., `[System.Windows.Forms.Label]`) instead of individual *instances* (note that, similarly, `Update-TypeData -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label ...` would only make newly defined members available on *already-existing instances*).

```
# Define a Create() method for the label *type* that acts as a factory
# method and outputs a new label *instance*.
# Note that the method becomes an *instance method* of the *type* object.
Add-Member -Force -InputObject ([System.Windows.Forms.Label]) -MemberType ScriptMethod `
           -Name Create -Value {                                                                #`#
  param(
    [int[]] $Location,
    [int[]] $Size,
    [string] $Text
  )
  New-Object $this.FullName -Property @{
    Location = New-Object Drawing.Point $Location[0], $Location[1]
    Size = New-Object Drawing.Size $Size[0], $Size[1]
    Text = $Text
  } 
}

# Call the type's new instance method with the desired arguments.
$amuletLabelValueDmg = [System.Windows.Forms.Label].Create((10,20), (60,20), 'Value')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create `custom object` and add `methods` those will set common properties the way you need. Like so:

```
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod `
           -InputObject $Label `
           -Name 'Value' `
           -Value {
                $This.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
                $This.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
                $This.Text = 'Value'
                return $This
            } -Force

Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod `
           -InputObject $Label `
           -Name 'Health' `
           -Value {
                $This.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
                $This.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
                $This.Text = 'Health'
                return $This
            } -Force

Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod `
           -InputObject $Label `
           -Name 'Resistance' `
           -Value {
                $This.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60) 
                $This.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
                $This.Text = 'Resistance'
                return $This
            } -Force


$Value = $Label.Value()
$Health = $Label.Health()
$Resistance = $Label.Resistance()
```

Comment: Instead of creating 3 different labels, variables `$Value`, `$Health` and `$Resistance` all point to the very same label instance, which ends up having the properties set by the _last_ method call, `.Resistance()`.